# $criteria->addAsColumn("lastRow", MAX(self::ID)); gives error?

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

i have this code:

```
static public function getLastNewMessage($profile_id)
{
    $c = new Criteria();
    $subSelect = "rc_message_box_table.profile_id_from NOT IN ( SELECT rc_blocklist_table.profile_id_block   FROM  rc_blocklist_table   WHERE  profile_id = $profile_id  ) and rc_message_box_table.profile_id_to=$profile_id and opened_once = 0";
    $c->add(self::PROFILE_ID_TO, $subSelect, Criteria::CUSTOM);
    $c->addAsColumn("lastRow", MAX(self::ID));
    //$subSelect2 = "max(rc_message_box_table.id)";
    //$c->add(self::ID, $subSelect2, Criteria::CUSTOM);
    return self::doSelect($c);
}
```

and get this error:

```
 500 | Internal Server Error | PropelException [wrapped: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS lastRow FROM rc_message_box_table` WHERE rc_message_box_table.profile_id_fro' at line 1]
```

i just want the record of MAX(auto-increment-field) on the rc_message_box_table and this field is ID
i have tried the commented out lines as well but nothing works. i dont know how to achieve this..please help?
thank you

Comment: I think you need to wrap MAX in quotes: `$c->addAsColumn("lastRow", 'MAX( ' . self::ID . ' )');`

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra ` in your SQL, where does that come from? It is right next to:

```
AS lastRow FROM rc_message_box_table`
```

Comment: here the full error: [wrapped: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS lastRow FROM `rc_message_box_table` WHERE rc_message_box_table.profile_id_fro' at line 1]